# Django url namespaces giving errors

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am new to the django framework. I currently started learning from an online video tutorial and I came across some errors. I have an app called groups which has two separate view files namely company and family. Due to that I have my groups/url file as this:

```
    from django.urls import path, include, re_path


    from . views import company
    from . views import family

    app_name = 'groups'

    company_patterns = [
        path('create/', company.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
        re_path(r'^edit/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', company.Update.as_view(), name='update'),
        path('<str:slug>/', company.Details.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ]

    family_patterns = [
        path('create/', family.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
        path('edit/<str:slug>/', family.Update.as_view(), name='update'),
        path('<str:slug>/', family.Details.as_view(), name='detail'),
]

    urlpatterns = [
        path('companies/', include(company_patterns, namespace='companies')),
        path('families/', include(family_patterns, namespace='families')),
    ]
```

But anytime I run the application from my dashboard template. I get this error:

'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Please, can anyone assist me with further explanation and solution? thank you

Answer (score 1):

define app_name in another urls.py file